# C# equivalent of the C++ custom project Wizard

Tags: visual-studio, wizard, envdte

I have an existing wizard template created for VC++ from year back, ported to VS2008. It uses the custom wizard jscript/html templating system and DTE object. I've used this successfully for years, but now I want to create an entry for a standard C# project, I see there's no way to customise the C# project settings - the methods are for VC++ only.

Is there something closely related to this for C# projects (or do I have to learn yet another way of creating a wizard for .net apps?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And it turns out to be "[Project Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s365byhx.aspx)" (for non-VC++ projects)

Answer (score 1):

I think they call this stuff recipes now. You may want to go in the direction the [Smart Client Software Factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480482.aspx) goes. It works via the [Guidance Automation Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/aa718948.aspx).

I'm sorry I can't provide any further info, have never worked with it. Hope I could help you though.

Comment: cheers. Looks like there's a whole heap of crud available now - recipes, templates, wizards and my favourite "Text Template Transformation Templates"... and a new framework to install. I may craft the project files 'by hand' instead.

Comment: ... or use t4, or codesmith, or I don't know what. Seriously, take a quick peek at t4.